# Downloads stop suddenly in 5ghz only

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireshark

Without the possibility of using a wired connection, I use a Wifi connection via tplink router an Intel Wifi 6E 160MHz card(latest Intel driver installed) on Windows 10.

I use an application (latest version) to legally download France TV videos.

However and only on this application, downloads pose a problem and stop suddenly or during operation and the application no longer responds when the connection is positioned on the 5GHz band, this band is potentially suitable for higher speeds on all browsers (Firefox, Edge, Chrome, etc.).

I noticed 14% errors of tranmissions.

This flow break does not occur when the connection is located in Wifi N (2.4GHz) with an overall lower speed.

I loaded these 2 types of connection into Wireshark for comparison without being able to interpret them, due to lack of experience.

How to resolve this in wireshark or other?

Comment: Have you rebooted your router/accesspoint? I had a similar weird issue. My 5Ghz is perfect on my phone, got a new phone and it would connect and then at weird times just drop the 5Ghz connection, sometimes not able to pick it up again. I thought my new phone was faulty, but after I rebooted my access point, all problems went away. There were no problems on the 2.4Ghz band.

Comment: I am actually shocked that Intel would have released drivers for a WiFi6e card since WiFi6e support itself is limited to Windows 11.

Comment: This problem only occurs on this application, so it has no impact on browsers (Firefox, Edge, etc.).
No feedback from users of this application on a problem of this type.